# SQL Output in single row

Tags: plsql

I'm running a PLSQL script to output rows like below:
[image]

However, is there a way i can output this in a single row with the last column data concatenated like below:
[image]

Comment: You are looking for string aggregation. Try using the string_agg() function.

Comment: By "PL/SQL script", do you mean "SQL query"? PL/SQL is a programming language and doesn't have tabular output.

Answer (score 1):

`listagg()` can be used to concat multiple rows into single row output. 2nd arg in the `listagg()` function is optional you may remove or replace it with anything of your choice.

```
SELECT EMPID, NAME, AGE, listagg(EDUCATION, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY EMPID) AS emp_qualification FROM Employees GROUP BY EMPID, NAME, AGE;
```

Live demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/336676/3